# How can I pass data from parent to child view?

Tags: ios, ios7, uistoryboardsegue, pass-data, uicontainerview

I have a container view, which uses a storyboard embed segue to load an embedded static table view. The segue ID is 'CONTAINER'.

When I run the following code, the prepareForSegue never actually gets called so no data is passed from the parent to the child.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

if ([sGender isEqualToString:@"MALE"]) {
    containerGender = @"MALE";

    if ([containerGender isEqualToString:@"MALE"]){
        NSLog(@"MALE");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"BROKEN");
    } 
}
else if ([sGender isEqualToString:@"FEMALE"]) {
    containerGender = @"FEMALE";
}
}


-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CONTAINER"]) {
    if([containerGender isEqualToString:@"MALE"]) {

        if ([containerGender isEqualToString:@"MALE"]){
            NSLog(@"MALE");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"BROKEN");
        } 


        SportTableViewController *tableView = segue.destinationViewController;
        tableView.sportGender = @"MALE";    
    }
    else if ([containerGender isEqualToString:@"FEMALE"]){
        SportTableViewController *tableView = segue.destinationViewController;
        tableView.sportGender = @"FEMALE";    
    }
}
}
```

My question is:

a)Why is prepareForSegue not called? Does the Storyboard Embed Segue behave differently to a standard seque?

b)Is there a better way of passing data from the container view to the embedded table?

Also please ignore the messy implementation/various log tests, just my attempts to work out whats going wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: Actually its not, I'm well aware of how to pass data. Its apparent my question came from a simple misunderstanding of how container views work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question actually stems from a misunderstanding of how container views load their embedded views. Apparently, it all happens before viewDidLoad. That means my conversion of sGender into containerGender took place too late.

I fixed it by passing sGender to the embedded view directly. I had thought I'd already tried this, but yesterday was obviously a slow day ;).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it..

try
in childViewController
set-

@property(nonatomic,retain)parentViewController *parent;

and

in ParentViewController set-

ChildViewController *child = [[childviewController alloc]init];
  child.parent=self;

It will set your parent class in childview and you can get data through parent object in child view controller.